# laravel, cleaner way to assign variable to a modal

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, forms, laravel-blade

I'm on a "blade" page that have:

```
<a
type="button"
data-passage="{{$passage}}"
class="btn btn-warning btn-xs editPassageButton"
data-toggle="modal"
data-target="#editPassage">Edit</a>
```

Then a modal like:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editPassage"
                 tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                 aria-labelledby="favoritesModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close"
                                    data-dismiss="modal"
                                    aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title"
                                id="addPassageLabel">Modifica Brano</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            @php
                                $passage =  "?????????";
                            @endphp

                            {{ Form::model($passage, array('route' => array('passage.update', 'null'), 'method' => 'POST')) }}
```

etc. etc.

Then a script part like this:

```
$(function() {
         $('.editPassageButton').on("click", function (e) {
             passage = $(this).data('passage');
         });


     });
```

And it works properly, so I cannot well understand how to send it to the php variable on the modal (the part with ???????). I found several post that suggest to send it trough a form, but it seem tricky to me, and for Laravel how it works?
 do i need to add a route in that case? no cleaner way to do it? I know how to pass single variable to a modal form, but i prefer to using the variable that is the model that i need to update...

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Laravel Form has been deprecated since 4.2, if I remember correctly.

Comment: im just mixing some tutorial things with laravel collective html facade, im on 5.4 right now, but i dont think that is the problem in this case

Comment: This is just your view. Have you built your model and controller accordingly?

Comment: create form along with some hidden fields (as per your requirements) and when click on edit button assign value to hidden field and when you post that form it will available on controller.

Comment: what exactly you want to do with modal form? you want to display some value on form and update?

Comment: @NarayanSharma yes.... and it comes from a table, so i need to put the right value on $passage variable and not just the last of the loop! I know how to it field by field, but i wondering if there is a way to doing on fly passing the whole model...

Comment: @JahStation you can not do this. http is stateless protocol you can't save the state of variable without using session, cookie and hidden fields.

Comment: ok so i need to perform it through form :( thanks